# Is there a way to find the next perfect square?

Tags: python, square

This is my code, however it only returns the next number (eg taking 121 it returns 122 instead of 144), but I dont understand why.

```
import math 
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    if math.sqrt(sq).is_integer:
        sqnext = sq + 1
        if math.sqrt(sqnext).is_integer:
            return sqnext
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: `.is_integer` is a method, but you're not calling it. `math.sqrt(sq).is_integer()` tests if the value returned from sqrt is an integer, whereas `math.sqrt(sq).is_integer` is a built-in method object which is always considered True in an if statement.

Comment: (Your logic is also wrong)

Comment: 4 is the square of 2. Why would you think that the next square is either 5 or nothing? (If `sq` is a square, it can be written `x * x`. The next square greater than `sq` is `(x + 1) * (x + 1)`, not `sq+1`, and no test is necessary).

Comment: Note that `math.sqrt(sq).is_integer()` is a flawed way to test if a number is square. It fails for negative numbers (an exception is raised) and large numbers where rounding (or inexpressibility as a double) cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. With `sqnext = sq + 1`, you are calculating the next number and not the next square.

Try this:

```
import math 
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    if math.sqrt(sq).is_integer:
        sqnext = math.sqrt(sq) + 1
        return sqnext * sqnext
    else:
        return -1
        
print(find_next_square(121))
```

**EDIT**

It looks like `is_integer` method is flawed and gives incorrect values as pointed by Henry. The below code works for positive integers up to a certain limit.

```
import math
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise   
    if int(math.sqrt(sq))**2 == sq:
        sqnext = math.sqrt(sq)
        return sqnext * sqnext
    else:
        return -1

print(find_next_square(5))
print(find_next_square(121))
```

Further since `sqrt` doesn't work for negative numbers, that needs to be handled separately:

```
import math
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    sign = -1 if sq < 0 else 1

    if int(math.sqrt(abs(sq)))**2 == abs(sq):
        sqnext = math.sqrt(abs(sq)) + sign * 1
        return sqnext * sqnext * sign
    else:
        return -1
        
print(find_next_square(5))
print(find_next_square(121))
print(find_next_square(-9))
```

Also, all the approaches above will not work for large numbers beyond a limit due to overflow issues.

Comment: Can you also test your code on -1, 5 and `(10 ** 10000)`? The results should be -1, -1, (some large number).

Answer (score 0):

The `is_integer` is a function not a variable, to call it you need to use '()' like with any function call

```
import math 
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    if math.sqrt(sq).is_integer():
        sqnext = sq + 1
        if math.sqrt(sqnext).is_integer():
            return sqnext
    else:
        return -1
```

although then you would be still checking only the following number of `sq` not the next square. You want increment the square root of `sq` and then return its square.

```
import math 
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    found_sqrt = math.sqrt(sq)
    if found_sqrt.is_integer():
        sqrt_incr = found_sqrt + 1
        return sqrt_incr * sqrt_incr
    else:
        return -1
```

Like other answers said after you get the square root of `sq` and it is indeed an integer, you add 1 and then return its square, thus getting the next perfect square.

Answer (score -1):

In `sqnext = sq + 1` you are adding 1 to the square of the previous number and assigning it to `sqnext` .

It should be `sqnext = (math.sqrt(sq)+1)**2`

```
import math 
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    if math.sqrt(sq).is_integer:
        sqnext = (math.sqrt(sq)+1)**2
        return sqnext
    else:
        return -1
```